# Page refreshes if the button is clicked for the second time - how to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have a button `test`. Upon the click, the 2 labels, `selectedZone` and `selectedLocation` are set with 2 dummy values. 
This works fine when the button is clicked for the first time. However after  the first click, the page refreshes and the labels are not set.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="language" content="en" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            function test()
            {
                //alert("in test fn");
                document.getElementById("selectedZone").innerHTML="ZONE TEST";
                document.getElementById("selectedLocation").innerHTML="LOCATION TEST";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="test();"> test </button>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label style="font-color='yellow'"> ZONE </label>
        <label id="selectedZone"></label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label style="font-color='yellow'"> LOCATION </label>
        <label id="selectedLocation"></label>
    </body>

</html>
```

P.S. justification for tagging  `jQuery Mobile`: I actually have a popup. There is a button inside that popup. Upon click of that button, the same `test()` is to be called.
Is there any extra code to be written (Eg: Callback) for the labels to be set with the same values as selected in the dropdown of the popup?

Comment: And... Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: After click it get the value. You are refreshing the page or it automatically refreshed

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Chrome 25 OSX.

Comment: @Салман No there are no errors.

Comment: @Peru Nope I am not refreshing. That's the point. Its getting refreshed automatically and the values set by the button are disappeared.

Comment: @PramodSetlur I am facing this problem. Did you find out why it was happening?

Comment: @Solace Sorry, this was 3years ago, i don't remember..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the html opening tag before head